# How to Drag and drop an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, drag-and-drop

```
document.getElementById('canvas_map').addEventListener(
    'dragstart', function(event) {
    var list_exe_selected=[];
    var image_match=[];
    //[...] code to find images image_match will be an htmlcollection
    list_exe_selected[i]=[];
    for (var j=0; j<image_match.length; j++) {
        var str=image_match[j].href.baseVal;
        list_exe_selected[i].push(str);
    };
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text', list_exe_selected);
}
document.getElementById('canvas_map').addEventListener(
    'dragover', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById('canvas_map').addEventListener(
    'drop', function(event) {
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    var list_exe_selected=data.split(',');
    for (var i=1; i<list_exe_selected.length; i++) {
        exe_selected=list_exe_selected[i];
        //do stuff
    };
};
```

First thing: in `dataTransfer.setData` `text` is the data type... good. Which other data type exist??? I can't find. Is there something for array?

Second thing: my `list_exe_selected` on `dragstart` is something like this:

```
[ <1 empty space>, "my_string1", Array[2], <3 empty spaces>, "my_string2"… ]
```

but my `data` on `drop` is this:

```
,my_string,first_element_of_my_array,second_element_of_my_array,,,,my_string2...
```

my array has been 'exploded' in his elements so my `list_exe_selected` do not have the same index like before and this is the problem...

Is there an easy way to resolve this problem? I could rebuild the array manually but maybe is possible to transfer the data without losing the format or is possible to pass more than one set of data...

Edit:
I can be wrong but at last it look like you can't pass array directly.

Comment: For future visitors, here is an explanation of dataTransfer types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Recommended_drag_types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with `event.dataTransfer` but it looks like since you're passing it text, you need to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` on the array. I have modified your code to include these.

```
document.getElementById('canvas_map').addEventListener(
    'dragstart', function(event) {
    var list_exe_selected=[];
    var image_match=[];
    //[...] code to find images image_match will be an htmlcollection
    list_exe_selected[i]=[];
    for (var j=0; j<image_match.length; j++) {
        var str=image_match[j].href.baseVal;
        list_exe_selected[i].push(str);
    };

    // Turns the array into a JSON string
    list_exe_selected = JSON.stringify(list_exe_selected);

    // saves the array as 'text' or a string
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text', list_exe_selected);
}
document.getElementById('canvas_map').addEventListener(
    'dragover', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById('canvas_map').addEventListener(
    'drop', function(event) {
    // gets the array as a string or 'text'
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');

    // formats the saved string into an array
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    var list_exe_selected=data.split(',');
    for (var i=1; i<list_exe_selected.length; i++) {
        exe_selected=list_exe_selected[i];
        //do stuff
    };
};
```

Documentation for [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

You may also want to take a look at the MDN page for [`dataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer).